# I am trying to implement text change and edit ends in TextInput using react-native but it's not quite working. Can any one help me?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to implement text change and edit ends in TextInput using react-native but it's not quite working.

[See the Screenshot Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMEFW.jpg)

Currently, when changing the price by touch input, the price is not affected when click off.

Here are my files

CartItem.js:

```
import React from "react";
import {
  View,
  TextInput,
  Image,
  TouchableOpacity,
  StyleSheet,
  Platform,
  Alert,
} from "react-native";
//Colors
import Colors from "../../../utils/Colors";
//NumberFormat
import NumberFormat from "../../../components/UI/NumberFormat";
//Icon
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import CustomText from "../../../components/UI/CustomText";
//PropTypes check
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

export class CartItem extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    const { item, onAdd, onDes, onRemove } = this.props;
    const AddItemHandler = async () => {
      await onAdd();
    };
    const sum = +item.item.price * +item.quantity;
    const checkDesQuantity = async () => {
      if (item.quantity == 1) {
        Alert.alert(
          "Clear cart",
          "Are you sure you want to remove the product from the cart?",
          [
            {
              text: "Cancel",
            },
            {
              text: "Yes",
              onPress: onRemove,
            },
          ]
        );
      } else {
        await onDes();
      }
    };
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.left}>
          <Image
            style={{
              width: "100%",
              height: 90,
              resizeMode: "stretch",
              borderRadius: 5,
            }}
            source={{ uri: item.item.thumb }}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.right}>
          <View
            style={{ flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: "space-between" }}
          >
            <CustomText style={styles.title}>{item.item.filename}</CustomText>
            <View>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={onRemove}>
                <MaterialCommunityIcons name='close' size={20} color='#000' />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </View>
          <CustomText style={{ color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 12 }}>
          Provided by Brinique Livestock LTD
          </CustomText>
          <NumberFormat price={sum.toString()} />
          <View style={styles.box}>



            <TouchableOpacity onPress={checkDesQuantity} style={styles.boxMin}>
              <MaterialCommunityIcons name='minus' size={16} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
```

Code that I would like to be fixed starts here.

```
            <View>
              <TextInput
              keyboardType='numeric' 
              onEndEditing={AddItemHandler} 
              style={styles.boxText}>{item.quantity}</TextInput>
            </View>
```

Code that I would like to be fixed ends here.

```
            <TouchableOpacity 
            onPress={AddItemHandler} 
            style={styles.boxMin}>
            
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name='plus' size={16} />
            </TouchableOpacity>



          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

CartItem.propTypes = {
  item: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  onAdd: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  onRemove: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  onDes: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginHorizontal: 10,
    height: 110,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: Colors.light_grey,
    flexDirection: "row",
    paddingVertical: 10,
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    borderRadius: 5,
    marginTop: 5,
  },
  left: {
    width: "35%",
    height: "100%",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  right: {
    width: "65%",
    paddingLeft: 15,
    height: 90,
    // overflow: "hidden",
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 14,
  },
  box: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    alignItems: "center",
    height: Platform.OS === "ios" ? 30 : 25,
    backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
    width: 130,
    borderRadius: 5,
    paddingHorizontal: 15,
    marginTop: 5,
  },
  boxMin: {
    width: "30%",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  boxText: {
    fontSize: 16,
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    padding: 5,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `onBlur` instead of `onEndEditing`.
2. How should the input end triggered?

   - After a time?
   - When user hits enter?
   - When user taps anywhere to close software keyboard?

Instead of

```
onEndEditing={AddItemHandler}
```

Use:

```
onBlur={(e) => {AddItemHandler(e.nativeEvent.text)}}
```

And ensure that AddItemHandler can handle the value in e.nativeEvent.text.

Comment: @MichealBahl 

As is, when the user taps anywhere to close the software keyboard the screen reloads and recalculation is done. When done, however, it is overridden by the add function and is increased by a quantity of one. I presume because I have added  `onEndEditing={AddItemHandler `

Comment: It is still overridden by the add function and is increased by a quantity of one. Thanks.